# How to add a dropdown to tab in viewpager sliding tabs?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I have 8 tabs in my app and i would like to provide easier access to the last 4 tabs which otherwise have to be scrolled till the end to reach.

According to Material design guidelines , we can use dropdown in tabs , by giving an option "more" as the last tab , and if the user selects a dropdown item , that item will appear on the penultimate tab and will be highlighted as the selected tab.

How to achieve this ? there are no documentation on how to do this ? only images are provided.

[Here's the link to material design guidelines for tabs](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage)

[Here's an image of tabs with an option "more"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4mja.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question , it might save someone's time if they decide to go on this road.Here's what i found out:-

I had posted a similar question on tabs about overflow pagination in TabLayout and recieved an answer from @ianhanniballake in which he mentioned that these features are for Desktop tabs and not supported in TabLayout.

[Here's the link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037360/how-to-provide-overflow-pagination-in-android-tab-layout/38041211#38041211)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu). Its easy to use, looks great.

Here is an example how I use it:

**Activity**

```
  View view = findViewById(R.id.action_settings);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final ListView listView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

            String[] functions = {getString(R.string.shareScreenshot), getString(R.string.shareDatei), getString(R.string.shareXML)};

            ListAdapter adapter = new CustomPopupAdapter(this, functions, listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            Display display = (this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay());
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            //int height = size.y;

            Resources resources = this.getResources();
            int navigationBarHeight = 0;
            int statusbarHeight = 0;
            int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                navigationBarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }

            resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                statusbarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }

            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
            popupWindow.setContentView(popupView);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.shadow_02327));
            } else {
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.shadow_02327));
            }
            popupWindow.setWidth(width);
            popupWindow.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0,  navigationBarHeight + statusbarHeight);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                  //Click handle
                }
            });
        }
```

**Adapter**

```
  public class CustomPopupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

            private String[] option;
            ListView owner;


        public CustomPopupAdapter(Context context, String[] option, ListView owner) {
            super(context, R.layout.custom_row_settings, option);
            this.option = option;
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_row_image_text, parent, false);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView tv = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText(option[pos]);


            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_photo_camera_grey_24dp);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_insert_drive_file_grey_24dp);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_code_grey_24dp);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_move_to_inbox_grey_24dp);
                    break;
            }

            return customView;
        }
    }
```

**popup.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how can i bring the selected option from the pop up menu to the last tab and show it as the selected tab?

Comment: The anchor in my example is null. Change it to the tab you want it! Then you should have it :)

Comment: this does not answer my question, i want to know how to set up tab with a dropdown , i know how to make pop up menu , but if you are suggesting to use popup menu in tabs , please explain how with code related to tabs.

Comment: that add the popup menu . you only have to set the anchor to the tab you want it.

Comment: i dont think we can add popup menu inside a tab..if you know how to do it, please update the answer on..how pop up menu can be added inside a tab..