# How to provide overflow pagination in android tab layout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-support-library, android-tablayout

According to Material design guidelines ,In android.support.design.widget.TabLayout when there are many tabs which cannot fit the screen size we can use overflow pagination , by providing a right arrow which when clicked will show all the remaining tabs by scrolling horizontally.How to achieve this?

[Here's an image of the same given in guidelines]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That pattern is in the 'Desktop tabs' section and therefore not supported by `TabLayout`, which is specifically targeting the 'Mobile tabs' section.

Comment: Please feel free to file a feature request at [b.android.com](http://b.android.com) if you'd like to see it added though!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer , i was not aware this is not supported by TabLayout , i would also like to know , if it is a bad design practice to have around 8 tabs in a mobile phone where only 4 tabs will fit the screen width at once.

Comment: Scrolling tabs (as you would need with 8 tabs) are generally best for categorization (think genres of music, etc) of content into a number of siblings. I wouldn't use 8 tabs for navigation through your app - that would be more appropriate in a navigation drawer, which scales much better to more items.

Comment: I think arrow support is necessary when overflow occurred. It will help user that there is more to see.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the tabMode to scrollable in the XML file

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to add pagination arrows but was able to add scrolling to tabview:

Surround your tabview with HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none" >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:tabMode="scrollable"
                        android:overScrollMode="never"
                        android:visibility="visible">
                    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```